# how to get current wishlist in magento

Tags: php, magento

guys sorry for bad English.
I am using in Magento enterprise I am working in wishlist there is a function in core at path

> C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\baab.bh\app\code\core\Mage\Wishlist\Helper\Data.php

```
getWishlist()
```

When I am calling this function to get wishlist from front-end **phtml** file it's giving me correct wishlist but when I am calling this function from **controller** it's giving me default wishlist only not the current wishlist here is the code of this function

```
public function getWishlist()
    {
        if (is_null($this->_wishlist)) {
            if (Mage::registry('shared_wishlist')) {
                $this->_wishlist = Mage::registry('shared_wishlist');
            } elseif (Mage::registry('wishlist')) {
                $this->_wishlist = Mage::registry('wishlist');
            } else {
                $this->_wishlist = Mage::getModel('wishlist/wishlist');
                if ($this->getCustomer()) {
                    $this->_wishlist->loadByCustomer($this->getCustomer());
                }
            }
        }
        return $this->_wishlist;
    }
```

I am calling it with the same code but it behaves differently from front-end **phtml** file and from **controller**. How can I get current wishlist from the controller as well?

Comment: current user wishlist ?

Comment: I am on wishlist page i need current wishlist object i need wishlist name

Answer (score 1):

For this, you will get all customers wishlist:

```
public function getWishlist()
{
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');

    $wishList = Mage::getModel('wishlist/wishlist')->loadByCustomer($customer);
    $wishListAllItem = $wishList->getItemCollection();

    if (count($wishListAllItem)) {
        $arrOfProductIds = array();

        foreach ($wishListAllItem as $item) {
            $arrOfProductIds[] = $item->getProductId();
        }
    }

    return $arrOfProductIds;
}
```

For this, you can get current user wishlist:

```
$wishList = Mage::getSingleton('wishlist/wishlist')->loadByCustomer($customer)
$wishListAllItem = $wishList->getItemCollection();

if (count($wishListAllItem)) {
    $arrOfProductIds = array();

    foreach ($wishListAllItem as $item) {
        $product = $item->getProduct();
        $arrOfProductIds[] = $product->getId();
    }
}
```

Comment: but i don't want collection dude i just need current wishlist name

Comment: @OBAID When user click on wishlist so you want to get that current wishlist name ? m right ?

Comment: Actually i have a button in wishlist page when user clicks it send an ajax to a function at that function i need this wishlist object